# When is $\nabla\cdot({\bf a}\cdot{\bf r})({\bf b}\cdot{\bf r})\,{\bf F}({\bf r})=0$ for constant vectors ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, divergence-operator, scalar-fields, divergence-theorem

When is the assertion that
$$\nabla\cdot({\bf a}\cdot{\bf r})({\bf b}\cdot{\bf r})\,{\bf F}({\bf r})=0$$
for constant vectors ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$ and a everywhere-divergenceless ${\bf F}$ true? The reason I ask is that I wish to prove
$$\iiint_VdV({\bf a}\cdot{\bf r})({\bf b}\cdot{\bf F})+({\bf b}\cdot{\bf r})({\bf a}\cdot{\bf F})=0$$
for the above vectors (with the additional requirement that ${\bf F}$ vanishes outside the enclosed volume $V$), and have obtained $({\bf a}\cdot{\bf r})({\bf b}\cdot{\bf F})+({\bf b}\cdot{\bf r})({\bf a}\cdot{\bf F})$ from the above divergence, but cannot proceed without proving that this divergence is indeed zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha} \def\b{\beta} \def\l{\lambda}
\def\f{F} \def\n{\nabla}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
$The divergence of a scalar-vector product is
$$\n\cdot(\l\f) = \f\cdot\LR{\n\l} + \l\LR{\n\cdot\f}$$
But if $\f$ is divergenceless this simplifies to
$$\n\cdot(\l\f) = \f\cdot\LR{\n\l}$$
Your particular scalar yields
$$\eqalign{
I &= \n r \\
\a &= \LR{r\cdot a} &\qiq \n\a = I\cdot a = a \\
\b &= \LR{r\cdot b} &\qiq \n\b = b  \\
\l &= \a\b &\qiq \n\l = \a b + \b a \\
}$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{
&\n\cdot(\l\f) = \f\cdot\LR{\a b + \b a} \;\doteq\; 0 \\
}$$
and your *assertion* is true when $\f$ is orthogonal to the vector in parentheses.

Comment: It may be better to match the initial notation by writing $\mathbf{F}$ rather than $f$, since the latter at first glance reads like a scalar function rather than a vector one.